# What's the name of this model? White spaceship, flexible panel with hexagon pattern?

Tags: set-identification

Can somebody tell me the set number of this  Model?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [7315 Solar Explorer](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7315-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D), from the Life on Mars subtheme from 2001.

[image]

Comment: That's it.  Thank you very much. 

This is a real nightmare.  I have dozens of sets from years ago.  The boxes and manuals were all neatly packed away in my storage unit (the Lego parts/blocks themselves safely in my home, thankfully) when everything in my storage unit fell victim to a fire... so I'm trying to identify each unit, get the assembly manual for each, and, if possible, find the original set box for as many as possible.

Comment: Under the "Teach a man how to fish" philosophy: It's fairly easy to look these up if you can spot an uncommon piece, and know the name of that piece (e.g. for this one I went with "Tile Round 2 x 2" for the printed round tile on top of the unit), then search at www.bricklink.com and browse through the results to get the piece, and from the piece go to all the sets the piece was in.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try next time.  I have several more to identify.  But... question:  what's the best way to find the correct name of a selected "uncommon piece".  Is there a place where it's easy to browse all the Lego parts by type, or color, in order to get the proper name?

Comment: Start with looking at the Catalog Tree at BrickLink: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P. That gives you an overview of how things are named. Main categories are "Brick" (the typical LEGO piece with studs on top), "Plate" (flat version of Brick; 3 plates stacked on top of eachother equal one brick) and "Tile" (a Plate without studs on top). If you look at the tree per the link I pasted, you can probably figure out what is in most of the other categories. From then on, it becomes a matter of searching often to get familiar with pieces and how they're called.